# How to get/read form post data in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm new in angular and i'm looking for method to get Form Post data? What i want to achieve is Website A will post the data to Website B, then Website B will use the data to perform the rest of the work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: WebsiteB's backend must consume that POST. Browser will not do this for you.

Comment: @Antoniossss the backend that you mean is refer to the typescript? or the server ?

Comment: You probably need to study a bit more around the concept of front/back-end https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_and_back_end
Basically the server on B needs to accept the POST and process it

Comment: understood. thanks for the help and explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a server with backend codes to handle your requests and responses between website A and website B. It means you can post your data from website A to the server, then website B can check for the new data in an interval Get request. Or you can use a web-socket to prevent from using interval in your case.